# How do I save an input file to a local folder in R-Shiny?

Tags: r

How can I save an input file to a specific location through Shinyapp?
This is the code I am using to input the file.

```
column(6, fileInput('file1', 'Choose File',
                      accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated- values,text/plain', '.txt', '.csv'), multiple = T),
                      actionButton('Click1', 'Add Data!'),
                      checkboxInput("header", "Header", T)
               ),
```

This is the code I am using to try and save the file:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {   
    outputDir <- "~/Dog_Park/DPData"
    saveData <- function(data) {
    # Create a unique file name
    fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv", as.integer(Sys.time()), digest::digest(data))
    # Write the file to the local system
    write.csv(
      x = data,
      file = file.path(outputDir, fileName))   }

     loadData <- function() {
    # Read all the files into a list
    files <- list.files(outputDir, full.names = TRUE)
    data <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
    # Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
    data <- do.call(rbind, data)
    data   }
     process <- function(data1){
    df <- as.data.frame(data1)
    df <- df[grep('00000',df$D),]
    df <- as.data.frame(df)
    df <- df %>% separate(df, c('Year','Month','Day', 'Time','Blank', 'TrafX_Count','Blank2')) 
    df <- sqldf("select Year, Month, Day, Time, TrafX_Count from df")
    df$TrafX_Count <- as.numeric(df$TrafX_Count)
    df$Date_Time <- paste( df$Year, df$Month, df$Day, df$Time)
    df <- sqldf("select Year, Month, Day, Time, sum(TrafX_Count), Date_Time from df group by Date_Time")
    df <- rename(df, 'TrafX_Count' = 'sum(TrafX_Count)')
    return(df)}
     #output$FileNames <- renderText()   observeEvent(input$Click1,{
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    NewFile <- read.delim(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    NewFile <- process(NewFile)
    saveData(NewFile)   })
```

It works when I run it locally on my computer but when I publish the app it stops working and says it cannot open the connection.

Comment: Are you publishing to "shinyapps.io"? Or how exactly are you publishing? A remote webserver will not have access to your local file system. That would be a big security issue.

Comment: I am publishing to "shinyapps.io".

Comment: I was looking at persistent data storage in Shiny apps and one of the options is local file system.  That is what I am trying to do.